Why do Firebase return "Analytics: Firebase Analytics is not supported in this environment" when connecting a NextJS app with Firebase Analytics?
I am currently building an web app using Firebase and Nextjs. I am having trouble adding analytics to the nextjs app in the firebase config file.
This is my Firebase config.ts file:
import { initializeApp, getApps, getApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAuth } from "firebase/auth";
import { getFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_API_KEY,
    authDomain: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_AUTH_DOMAIN,
    projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_PROJECT_ID,
    storageBucket: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_STORAGE_BUCKET,
    messagingSenderId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
    appId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_APP_ID,
    measurementId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_FIREBASE_MEASUREMENT_ID
};

const app = !getApps.length ? initializeApp(firebaseConfig) : getApp();

const auth = getAuth(app);

const db = getFirestore(app)

const storage = getStorage(app)

const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

export {app, auth, db, storage, analytics}

Every time i try to export analytics, i get this error:

@firebase/analytics: Analytics: Firebase Analytics is not supported in this environment. Wrap initialization of analytics in analytics.isSupported() to prevent initialization in unsupported environments. Details: (1) Cookies are not available. (analytics/invalid-analytics-context).

What is causing this error?
I tried doing this, but then i won't receive any data in my analytics realtime dashboard, so i was thinking, that it hadn't connected.
const analytics = isSupported().then(yes => yes ? getAnalytics(app) : null);


It seems like your code is trying to use the Firebase SDK for Google Analytics on the server, which is not supported.

If you want to use this SDK, you'll have to make sure all code that uses it ends up executing on the client-side only.

If you want to report analytics event from your server-side code, you can use the GA4 Measurement Protocol. There is no Firebase SDK for this, but the documentation shows how to call the REST API.



So it should work, if i put the "const analytics = getAnalytics(app);" inside a useEffect on my homepage? Can i then run "logEvent(analytics, 'notification_received')"?

That could work yes. If you can't get it to work, I recommend posting a new question with a minimal repro - as it's at that stage a client-side issue, not a server-side issue.
